# jQuery selector does not work for one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why doesn't this jQuery selector work at all?
Selecting another element such as $("body") or another div works fine.
This same selector works in CSS

Javascript:

```
$(".slideshow, .slideshow figure, .slideshow figure img").hover( function() {
    stopSlideshow();
    alert("HEY"); 
  }, 
  function(){
    startSlideshow();
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <?php
    $counter = 1;
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        echo "<figure>
                  <img src=\"" . $image . "\" width=\"1024\" height=\"600\"  />
                  <figcaption>ehojlhaiel;jgaelgkjnaqgjqaegaeg</figcaption>
              </figure>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Generated HTML :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3w6g.png

[image]

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: also `$(".slideshow, .slideshow figure, .slideshow figure img")` is not required... `$(".slideshow")` might be enough

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vhZS6/3/

Comment: Edited the post to include screenshot. I tried $(".slideshow") and it didn't work, that's why I tried including the child elements

Comment: Try `$(document).on('mouseenter', '.slideshow', function () {
    stopSlideshow();
    console.log("Stop");
}).on('mouseleave', '.slideshow', function () {
    startSlideshow();
    console.log("Start");
})`

Answer (score 1):

It is all about binding the hover event at the right time, when your `slideshow` div is actually loaded in the DOM. To fix it you could do this instead:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".slideshow", function(){
    //your code
});
```

This way you don't need to wait until your `slideshow` is loaded in the DOM.

The other way without using live events is to run your code once you add the `slideshow` to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery("div.slideshow").hover(function() { 
  // code inside here 
});
```

if this div is generate dynamically then do this

```
  jQuery("div.slideshow").on("hover",function() { 
      // code inside here 
    });
```